# How do I send a request to multiple urls and check the responses for a certain string value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to search a URL for a certain phrase.

For example, say a user types in 'Snowman' in an input field - I want the browser to search http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=2&page=1&itemsPerPage=14 for the phrase snowman. If the phrase snowman is found on the requested above, I want it to display 2 under the text-input field.

There's a catch however - I don't only want the browser only to search http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=2&page=1&itemsPerPage=14, I want it to also search userid=3, userid=4 up up to userid=100000000 for the phrase 'Snowman'.

So for example, if the phrase 'Snowman' is found on http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=245845&page=1&itemsPerPage=14, I want it to display 245845 under the input field.

For example, If the phrase 'Snowman' is found on say userid=53543 and userid=693 (these are random ids, not specific), I want it to display them both under the text input field.

I currently have this code, but it's not much use - it doesn't get the result from the input field and the userid doesn't ascend:

```
<script>
var word = "snowman",
    queue = [http://www.roblox.com/Trade/inventoryhandler.ashx?filter=0&userid=2&page=1&itemsPerPage=14],
    curr
;
while (curr = queue.pop()) {
    if (!curr.textContent.match(word)) continue;
    for (var i = 0; i < curr.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        switch (curr.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
            case Node.TEXT_NODE : // 3
                if (curr.childNodes[i].textContent.match(word)) {
                    console.log("Found!");
                    console.log(curr);
                    // you might want to end your search here.
                }
                break;
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE : // 1
                queue.push(curr.childNodes[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That would be very slow. You'd be better off searching on the server side.

Comment: Would a quicker option be to save the information to the database, so when someone searches for the same item, it can echo the information from the database, rather than search for it all again?

Comment: Full text search is not a trivial task performance-wise. I suggest taking a look at a search engine like [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/)

Comment: Is what I requested not possibly with Javascript/Jquery then?

Comment: It is, but you really don't want to do that, at least in an application meant for production. Consider a situation where you have a million users and each request to the backend would take e.g. 10 milliseconds. This way, searching through the whole database would require 10,000 seconds, i.e., approximately 3 hours of pure HTTP requests.

Comment: I understand, but I noted in my previous reply that couldn't we then save the owners of that specific item to a database, so it doesn't have to re-check for them?

Comment: That's basically what you would do with elastic, but preferably with a batch process. However, you wouldn't store them by search keys, but index all of the available data and search it afterwards.

Comment: It seems Elastic is a paid product.. is there not a code with Javascript/jQuery e.g which will work?